# When does Liquibase rollback statement come into play

Tags: liquibase

Let's say we have the following liquibase .sql file:

```
--liquibase formatted sql    
--changeset Jack:create_session_id_index rollbackSplitStatements:true runInTransaction:false
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ORDERS_IDX_SESSION_ID ON orders((orders_counter->>'sessionId'));
--rollback DROP INDEX ORDERS_IDX_SESSION_ID;
```

Here we create an index on json-field in `orders` table.
My question is about the commented statement:
`DROP INDEX ORDERS_IDX_SESSION_ID;`
Is it executed by liquibase automatically when something goes wrong? Ot is it just a prompt for developers? Which rollback statement should I write if at this moment I am not creating an index, but instead what to drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase has a feature called `rollback`. Not to be confused with database transaction rollback.

**To answer your questions:**

> Is it executed by liquibase automatically when something goes wrong?

No. If something goes wrong, the transaction rolls back. `--rollback` statement from the changeSet is not being executed.

> Ot is it just a prompt for developers?

No. If you want a prompt for developers, you may use the `<comment>` tag. Or I guess in SQL notation it'll be `--comment`. When you're writing `--rollback` in the changeSet, you refer to Liquibase "rollback" feature.

> Which rollback statement should I write if at this moment I am not creating an  index, but instead what to drop it?

That depends on the business logic. I guess the opposite of dropping an index will be createIndex.

**Some explanation:**

When Liquibase executes a changeSet, it does it within a **database** transaction. If the change in the changeSet fails, then transaction rollback kicks in and rolls everything back. It has nothing to do with `--rollback do-something` part of the changeSet.

Now if we're talking about Liquibase feature named `rollback`, then there's a pretty good piece of [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/rollback/rollback-by-tag.html). It describes the "types" of rollback and how it works.

> **rollback**
>
> The rollback command rolls back changes made to the database based on
> the specified tag.
>
> **Uses**
>
> The rollback command is typically used to revert all changes that were
> made to the database after the tag you specify.
>
> When you run rollback, Liquibase will roll back sequentially all the
> deployed changes until it reaches the tag row in the DATABASECHANGELOG
> table. For example, you can use the rollback command when you want to
> undo a series of changes made to your database related to a specific
> tag such as a numbered release. If you have tags for release 1,
> release 2, and release 3, and need to make a correction in release 2,
> the rollback command will rollback release 3 first.

Also there's a nice [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-rollback) with explanation and examples of how to use the `rollback` feature.

Comment: And does `runInTransaction:false` refer to database transaction? If so, then `false` value probably does not matter since we have only one statement in the changeset.

Comment: Yes, it refers to the database transaction. As I know, the `false` is not recommended. Check out https://forum.liquibase.org/t/help-understanding-runintransaction/1311/3